# Roslyn in memory compilation: CS0103: The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

So i'm having this problem.

I'm trying to compile code in memory and adding namespace references by searching the syntax tree so i do not add them manually. Trying to simulate how Visual Studio maybe does it.

I'm a bit over my head in the compilation department. Even if i add a metadata reference to System while reading the syntax tree it does not find System.Console.

The key is that i want it to include the assemblies by itself, i do not want to add a "MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(....,"System.Console").

I explained the code below so that is clear what is happening.

```
class App
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //creating the syntax tree for the program
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
            namespace ns{
                using System;
                public class App{
                    public static void Main(string[] args){
                        Console.Write(""dada"");
                    }
                }


            }");
        //creating options that tell the compiler to output a console application
        var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(
           OutputKind.ConsoleApplication,
           optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Debug,
           allowUnsafe: true);

        //creating the compilation
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(Path.GetRandomFileName(), options: options);

        //adding the syntax tree
        compilation = compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

        //getting the local path of the assemblies
        var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
        List<MetadataReference> references = new List<MetadataReference>();
        //adding the core dll containing object and other classes
        references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Private.CoreLib.dll")));
        references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "mscorlib.dll")));
        //gathering all using directives in the compilation
        var usings = compilation.SyntaxTrees.Select(tree => tree.GetRoot().ChildNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>()).SelectMany(s => s).ToArray();

        //for each using directive add a metadatareference to it
        foreach (var u in usings)
        {
            references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, u.Name.ToString() + ".dll")));
        }

        //add the reference list to the compilation
        compilation=compilation.AddReferences(references);

        //compile
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                    diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                    diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", diagnostic.Id, diagnostic.GetMessage(), diagnostic.Location);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                AssemblyLoadContext context = AssemblyLoadContext.Default;
                Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromStream(ms);
                assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { "arg1", "arg2", "etc" } });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console lives in mscorlib.dll. I don't sniff you adding it during compilation (not sure when or how to do that). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Will i added it, it has the same error

Answer (score 5):

- In the .net core `System.Console` lives in the `System.Console.dll`. So you need to add reference on it
- You need to add reference on the `System.Runtime.dll` to correctly resolve the predefined types: `object`, `bool` and so on
- `SyntaxNode.ChildNodes()` returns only child, that means it doesn't return the descendents nodes, so if you want to get all `UsingDirectiveSyntax` you should change your logic. As one of way just use `SyntaxNode.DescendantNodes()`

After applying all suggestions you just get something likes this (The parts that didn't change will skipped):

```
  ...
  //adding the core dll containing object and other classes
  references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Private.CoreLib.dll")));
  references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Console.dll")));
  references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll")));

  //gathering all using directives in the compilation
  var usings = compilation.SyntaxTrees.Select(tree => tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>()).SelectMany(s => s).ToArray();
  ...
```

Comment: The thing is that i do not want to follow that path. Having in the code "using System" i want to find a way for it to add itself what it needs for the console to work, in this care "System.Console". I thought of having it store the initial imports like System then for each one to add the descendants of it. So in this case importing System in code will end up importing at compilation all it's first level children. But i do not really understand how it works. In Visual Studio when you write the code you say using System and it compiles just fine. I want to try something similar

Comment: I am importing System.Private.CoreLib.dll manually because it has the object definition and a few classes that you do not find in System

Comment: Do you know that you can declare the custom `System` namespace in your custom library (Foo.dll)? And how will you automatially add the correct library (Foo or System.Console) to compilation just looking at the `UsingDirectiveSyntax`? VS know about `System.Console.dll` because VS references the coressponding SDK that exactly contains `System.Console.dll`, `System.Private.CoreLib.dll` and so on. So when it see `using System` it try to find FQN type from library that are referenced or from search paths. So in the common case you cann't add reference  just looking at the `UsingDirectiveSyntax`.